# create-react-app and TypeScript error: 'React' must be in scope when using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I initialised a React project with TypeScript using the CLI command `create-react-app client --typescript`. Then, I ran `npm start` but received the following compilation error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 26:13:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
```

I did not even modify the boilerplate project provided by `create-react-app` other than removing unnecessary logo files, and my previous React apps done using TypeScript compiled just fine. Below is my `App.tsx` and `index.tsx` file: (note that the logo in `App.tsx` was removed, and I did not touch `index.tsx`)

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        Lorem
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`React` and `ReactDOM` are imported, so what caused this error?

Edit:

I found out that `npm start`, which runs `react-scripts start`, is compiling my `.tsx` files into `.js` files, which probably caused this issue. What might have caused the above behaviour?

Comment: Well the error says _./src/App.js_ but shouldn’t it be _.tsx_?

Comment: @Jason Oh wait this is really true. I've figured out that ```react-scripts``` is apparently compiling my ```.tsx``` files into ```.js``` files, which shouldn't happen. I've updated ```create-react-app``` to the latest version, but the error persists. Any solutions, or should I revert to an older version of ```create-react-app```?

Comment: That's coming from ESLint, not TypeScript. If there is an old `src/App.js` file, delete it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Then I get the error ```Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/.../Desktop/projects/project_name/client/src/App.js'```. The script is also mistakenly looking for an ```index.js``` file as the entry point, so deleting the ```index.js``` file also throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const RootApp:React.FC = () => {
  return (
     <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
  );
}

render(<RootApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Does not work. I think the error comes from ```react-scripts``` somehow compiling my ```.tsx``` files into ```.js``` files.